# What is the best approach to load data into Hive using NiFi?

Tags: hdfs, hiveql, apache-nifi, data-ingestion

I have started working with NiFi. I am working on a use case to load data into Hive. I get a CSV file and then I use SplitText to split the incoming flow-file into multiple flow-files(split record by record). Then I use ConvertToAvro to convert the split CSV file into an AVRO file. After that, I put the AVRO files into a directory in HDFS and I trigger the "LOAD DATA" command using ReplaceText + PutHiveQL processor.

I'm splitting the file record by record because to get the partition value(since LOAD DATA doesn't support dynamic partitioning). The flow looks like this:

**GetFile** (CSV) --- **SplitText** (split line count :1 and header line count : 1) --- **ExtractText** (Use RegEx to get partition fields' values and assign to attribute) --- **ConvertToAvro** (Specifying the Schema) --- **PutHDFS** (Writing to a HDFS location) --- **ReplaceText** (LOAD DATA cmd with partition info) --- **PutHiveQL**

The thing is, since I'm splitting the CSV file into each record at a time, it generates too many avro files. For ex, if the CSV file has 100 records, it creates 100 AVRO files. Since I want to get the partition values, I have to split them by one record at a time. I want to know is there any way, we can achieve this thing without splitting record by record. I mean like batching it. I'm quite new to this so I am unable to crack this yet. Help me with this.

PS: Do suggest me if there is any alternate approach to achieve this use case.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to group the Avro records based on the partitions' values, one Avro file per unique value? Or do you only need the partitions' values for some number of LOAD DATA commands (and use a single Avro file with all the records)?

If the former, then you'd likely need a custom processor or ExecuteScript, since you'd need to parse, group/aggregate, and convert all in one step (i.e. for one CSV document). If the latter, then you can rearrange your flow into:

**GetFile** -> **ConvertCSVToAvro** -> **PutHDFS** -> **ConvertAvroToJSON** -> **SplitJson** -> **EvaluateJsonPath** -> **ReplaceText** -> **PutHiveQL**

This flow puts the entire CSV file (as a single Avro file) into HDFS, then afterwards it does the split (after converting to JSON since we don't have an EvaluateAvroPath processor), gets the partition value(s), and generates the Hive DDL statements (LOAD DATA).

Comment: I actually did the first one without using a custom processor. I used MergeContent to do the batching. It now works the way I want. However, I'm intrigued by the second idea. I'll try that out. I have one question though. Since we are having only one AVRO file in HDFS and we'll be giving that HDFS path in LOAD command, after reading the partitions' values and when we trigger the LOAD DATA command, how the records get moved to Hive across all the partitions? Can part of the AVRO files be moved? I mean like the single AVRO gets split into multiple AVRO and put into the corresponding partitions?

Comment: Turns out the second way won't work because all partitions will end up with the same data. If you used RouteOnAttribute then MergeContent before PutHDFS then that sounds like the right way to go.

Comment: Yep. The second one will put everything into a single partition. By the way, I din't use RouteOnAtrribute. MergeContent with its Correlation Attribute property just did the job. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If you've placed the file at the location where the hive table is reading the data using the puthdfs processor then you don't need to call the puthiveql processor. I am also new to this but I think you should leverage the schema-on-read capability of hive.